# Silverlight4 page and PrincipalPermission

Tags: silverlight-4.0, principalpermission

I am using VS2010 to learn about Silverlight4 Business Application with the MVVM design pattern.

Trying to figure out how to declaratively secure a SL4 view (either a Page or UserControl or ChildWindow).

I recall in an ASP.NET 2.0 web application, I could have put the PrincipalPermission attribute on my webpage.

Example:

```
using System.Security.Permissions;

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated=true, Role="Manager")]
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{//blab blab
}
```

Seem cannot do that in the "SL4" project as it would not even let me set a reference to the System.Security.

My google search keeps returning results about securing the WCF method calls, which is fine as another layer of security; but I would also like to do declarative security on the SL view itself too.

Anyone has any ideas?
(remember I am new to SL development)

Thanks
Sheir

Answer (score 1):

I think you either want 
`[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated=true]`
or
`[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Manager")]`

the latter means you are logged in / and your IPrinciple is associated with a role of manager...

the first one means you are just logged in - ergo a valid user.